# Can't get my old Entity in preUpdate Sonata

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-sonata

Here's the deal, i'm trying to update an Entity, but i'd like to compare the state of my entity before the update with the state of my entity after the update.

I try to compare the number of Users in my entity.

For example, if i add a User, i want my code to know that, for example, i had 4 Users before update, and 5 after (and get that User for further use).

After reading different topics, i've tried doing like that in my `preUpdate($object){}` method

```
$em = this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$original = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($object);
```

But both

```
var_dump(count($object->getUsers()));
var_dump(count($original['users']));
```

Give the same value, and, according to my example, the value is 5 in both case (so the value after the update).

Is there a way i can save the old_state of my entity in a var? What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:
It's not the preUpdate function of Doctrine, but the preUpdate function of SonataAdmin, don't know if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in the preUpdate function:

```
    $em = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass());
    $original = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($object);
```

Comment: Sorry i couldn't answer this weekend.. I've just tried this and it doesn't work, i have the same result as what i had